# CoffeeScript : Array of Objects to an Object

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have an array of object

```
arrayObj = [
{ "a" : [1,2,3,4]} , { "b" : "Hello World"} ]
```

I want to convert this too,

```
obj = { "a" :  [1,2,3,4] , "b" : "Hello World" }
```

Comment: And where exactly are you stuck? Don't you know how to iterate over an array? Or how to add properties to an object? Both of these are either explained in a JS tutorial or have been asked before.

Comment: @FelixKling I believe OP is stuck at the "has to code" stage. What he is looking for is someone to write that code so he can solve his 'having to code' problem. One possible solution to OP's problem is complete working code OP can copy-paste into his production app, reading the said code is optional.

Comment: All I wanted to know is that is there a function in libraries like underscore.js to implement this. Apologies if you find the question lame. I know how to iterate over an array, i guess everyone here viewing this post would know that. But at times there are smarter ways to do things which people can learn using such forums. Anyways My Apologies to you guys...

Comment: *"All I wanted to know is that is there a function in libraries like underscore.js to implement this"* Then why didn't you ask that? The answer is: no. You have to iterate over the array and add properties to an object, one way or the other.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.!

Comment: *All I wanted to know is that is there a function in libraries like underscore.js to implement this* -- actually, there is: [`_.extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend). `obj = _.extend {}, arrayObj...`.

Comment: @Linus _.extend doesnt do the job here. I beleive there is no way other then writing your own function :)

obj = _.extend {} , [{"name" : "Ankit" } , {"last name" : "Solanki" }
//{ 0 : {"name" : "Ankit" } , 1 : {"last name" : "Solanki" } }

Comment: Well, that's when you pass an array as an argument, but with CoffeeScript's [splats](http://coffeescript.org/#splats), it's a different story. `foo = [{a: 1}, {b: 2}]; _.extend {}, foo...;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Reduce method of an array. 
Example

```
arrayObj.reduce(
  function(prevValue,curValue){
    prevValue[Object.keys(curValue)[0]] = curValue[Object.keys(curValue)[0]];
    return prevValue;
  }
,
 {}
)
```

Note: This would overwrite property values(on the result) if same property name is repeated in different objects of the initial array. Also works for first properties only right now. Could be extended to all the keys of each containing object.